# How to get fish-style formatting with less

Tags: ls, less, fish

Let's say I run a command like `ls` in fish and get lots of output, how do I scroll through it and still keep the fish formatting or something like it?

`ls | less` doesn't keep the formatting.

I know now that the coloring is due to `ls` being run as `ls -G`. `ls -G` produces the same coloring on the default shell on OSX. This suggests that maybe the question is about `ls` and not about fish.

On Arch, `ls -C --color=always | less -R` does it.

Comment: I'm not able to check just no. I suspect you'd need `ls --color=always` and then an option for `less` to interpret the color sequences

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because of BSD ls, not fish. There's no --color=always, you have to export CLICOLOR_FORCE.

So something like

`alias lsless="set -gx CLICOLOR_FORCE ''; ls | less; set -e CLICOLOR_FORCE"`
would do it.

Another option would be to just `brew install coreutils` and then `gls --color=always | less`